# When do the events of “Thrawn” end in relation to “A New Hope”?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, a-new-hope, star-wars-thrawn

How much time is there between *Thrawn* and the beginning of *A New Hope*?

What I’m really looking for is a timeline (in BBY) of Thrawn’s notable activities/events, including the Thrawn trilogy (even though the novels themselves are still Legends) if someone is willing to share. But my original question is my main inquiry.

Comment: Note: there is a new "Thrawn" nove, released in April 2017. Do you mean precisely the "Legends'" Thrawn?

Comment: @TimSparrow - My question is about the 2017 novel, *Thrawn*. Although Thrawn himself has been re-canonized, I don’t think the original Thrawn trilogy itself has been. I only mention that because I would also like to see a Thrawn timeline taken from everything written about him.

Answer (score 1):

### About two years<sup>1</sup>

Shortly after the *Thrawn* novel was announced, Timothy Zahn was [interview by StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/news/qa-with-timothy-zahn), and he said that the events of the novel dovetailed into season 3 of *Star Wars: Rebels* (where Thrawn is a primary antagonist):

> **Q: Can you give us any hints about the story and what readers will learn in the new book?**
>
> *Thrawn* will span several years of the *Star Wars* timeline, beginning with his first encounter with the Empire and ending just before the opening of *Rebels* Season 3.

This is somewhat supported by the novel itself, which ends with Thrawn being promoted to his iconic rank:

> The throne room was as Thrawn remembered it, though he saw it now with different eyes. The new uniform he'd been given was white, with gold shoulder bars and silver collar insignia, completely unlike anything else in the Imperial Navy. The rank insignia plaque the Emperor held in his gnarled hand was equally impressive: twelve tiles in blue, red, and gold.
>
> The Emperor's face was as Thrawn had never seen it. His expression holds satisfaction, with hints of both amusement and malice. "Congratulations, Grand Admiral," he said as he held out the insignia plaque. "An excellent day for you. An excellent day for my Empire."
>
> <sup>*Thrawn* Chapter 29</sup>

And his first appearance on *Rebels* has him note that his promotion was "recent":

> **Tarkin:** Grand Admiral Thrawn.
>
> **Konstantine:** "Grand Admiral"?
>
> **Thrawn:** The Emperor recently promoted me after my victory at Batonn.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars: Rebels* Season 3 Episode 1: "Steps into Shadow"</sup>

As Pablo Hidalgo confirmed [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/771832098231504896), the season 3 premiere of *Rebels* is about two years before *A New Hope*:

[image]

> **@pablohidalgo** six months pass between the S2 finale and the S3 premiere. We're about 2 years from Ep4

Unfortunately, I'm not sure there's enough information given in the novel to construct an accurate timeline of events. There is some information, and I've made a few attempts, but the fact that the novel portrays two interweaving narratives has been throwing me off more than slightly. All I'm prepared to state with confidence right now is that Thrawn made contact with the Empire no later than 6 or 7 BBY.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm deliberately not counting the epilogue, which [takes place](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167526/31051) in an ambiguous timeframe, possibly after Thrawn's death